# Laravel Eloquent not getting binary data from server when live

Tags: php, laravel

first of all sorry for bad english.
I am new to laravel with mongodb.
I am using laravel eloquent for getting data from remote mongo database.
I am trying to fetch BSON object from the database, when I run my project on local system the result is fine.
But same code on live server returning empty BSON object. I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information to help you properly. What database do you connect to locally? What database do you connect to in production? Is the object you're trying to retrieve even there? etc etc

Comment: I am connected mongo DB remotely, the same database is accessed locally and in production.